# Remove bottom padding on widgets

Tags: android, padding

As you can see in the link below there is an extra padding (around 2mm) below the EditText field. I can't seem to remove this padding in anyway. This occurs with other widgets as well (like Buttons). It looks like Android is default adding this extra padding to all elements.

http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/4000/bottompadding.png

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that is a function of the background image. Specifically, `textfield*.9.png` would appear to be your culprits (5 total images). You could take those images from your SDK, eliminate the extra padding, create a custom `StateListDrawable` that references them, and so forth.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!

That is weird though why they choose to add extra padding for the widgets.

Comment: Hi, would setting the background=@null help, then? I tried, along with setting padding=0dip, layout_margin=0dip, but still on my Nexus S, my TextViews still have unwanted padding.

Answer (score 0):

After API 16 you can use the setViewPadding Method:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setViewPadding(int, int, int, int, int)